# Magento install page pops in production website while normally navigating

Tags: magento

The webshop has this nasty problem that +/- 1 out of 12 pageloads the install page from Magento pops up. I cleared the caches, renamed var folder, so Magento would create a new one. My local.xml has the installation date. My config-files are readable (644). In Mage.php i removed the installation redirect. Still it keeps coming. I really don't know whats going on while it seems very random.

Comment: can't you just remove install.php and see how it goes?

Comment: Thats the weird problem. When i delete it. I still get the /index.php/install/ -page randomly. fortunately it is not possible to reinstall. The button simply wont work. Weird stuff..

Comment: Are you using Varnish or some kind of full page caching solution?